# need to optimize this view query under the left join

Tags: mysql

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `view_pendinginvoices`$$

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view_pendinginvoices` AS 
SELECT
  `p`.`mrno`             AS `MRNO`,
  CONCAT(`p`.`patientname`) AS `PATIENTNAME`,
  `v`.`patient_visit_id` AS `visitno`,
  SUM(`pb`.`amount`)     AS `amount`,
  `p`.`patient_id`       AS `patient_id`,
  `v`.`visit_date`       AS `visit_date`,
  `v`.`visittype`        AS `visittype`,
  `v`.`site_id`          AS `site_id`,
  `v`.`visitid`          AS `visitid`
FROM (((`patient` `p`
LEFT JOIN `prefix_master` `pm`
   ON ((`pm`.`id` = `p`.`patprefix`)))
JOIN `view_pendinginvoices_sub` `pb`
   ON ((`p`.`patient_id` = `pb`.`PATIENTID`)))
JOIN `visit` `v`
   ON ((`v`.`visitid` = `pb`.`VISIT_ID`)))
GROUP BY `p`.`mrno`,`pm`.`prefix`,`p`.`patientname`,`v`.`patient_visit_id`,`p`.`patient_id`,`v`.`visit_date`,`v`.`visittype`,`v`.`site_id`,`v`.`visitid`
;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It is nice if you tell us what you want to do ?

Comment: Optimising views in MySQL is a bit of a nonsense because views in MySQL are anyway suboptimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking to your code  seems that a lot of () are unuseful  and also the concat with  single value

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `view_pendinginvoices`$$

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
    VIEW `view_pendinginvoices` AS 
SELECT
  `p`.`mrno`             AS `MRNO`,
  `p`.`patientname`      AS `PATIENTNAME`,
  `v`.`patient_visit_id` AS `visitno`,
  SUM(`pb`.`amount`)     AS `amount`,
  `p`.`patient_id`       AS `patient_id`,
  `v`.`visit_date`       AS `visit_date`,
  `v`.`visittype`        AS `visittype`,
  `v`.`site_id`          AS `site_id`,
  `v`.`visitid`          AS `visitid`
FROM `patient` `p`
    LEFT JOIN `prefix_master` `pm` ON `pm`.`id` = `p`.`patprefix`
    JOIN `view_pendinginvoices_sub` `pb` ON `p`.`patient_id` = `pb`.`PATIENTID`
    JOIN `visit` `v` ON `v`.`visitid` = `pb`.`VISIT_ID`
GROUP BY `p`.`mrno`
        ,`pm`.`prefix`
        ,`p`.`patientname`
        ,`v`.`patient_visit_id`
        ,`p`.`patient_id`
        ,`v`.`visit_date`
        ,`v`.`visittype`
        ,`v`.`site_id`
        ,`v`.`visitid`
;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and if you need  immprove performance be sure you have proper index on the columns involved in join

```
create index  idx1  on patient (patient_id, patprefix )
```

Comment: yes, this we had already added , here i need to reduce to joins, if there is any option kindly advise me